# Reference Variable sheet name in vlookup

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I would like to reference a variable sheet name within a Vlookup however struggling to place the "'" in the correct place. Can anyone let me know where I am going wrong?

```
  CM1.Range("G5").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6]," & CM.Name & "!C[-6],1,FALSE)"
```

Code produces;
 =VLOOKUP(A5,Sep-'16'!A:A,1,FALSE)

Required formula:
 =VLOOKUP(A6,'Sep-16'!A:A,1,FALSE)

Comment: `CM1.Range("G5").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'" & CM.Name & "'!C[-6],1,FALSE)"`

Comment: As @Nathan_Sav says, and do not have any single quote characters in the worksheet name...